# WPF ListBox, how to hide border and change selected item background color?

Tags: wpf, control-template

I'd like to hide the border of ListBox, and make background of selected item the same as unselected ones.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

To hide the border, use

```
<ListBox BorderThickness="0"/>
```

If you don't want to have a selection, use an `ItemsControl` instead of the `ListBox`.

The following code hides the border around the ListBox and does always show a white background on the item (if its generated through the `ItemsSource`-property).

```
<ListBox BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
              <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Background="White">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

If you use ListViewItem-instances, you must change the background there.

**UPDATE**

### In the meantime I have found a solution that is IMO much more elegant:

```
<ListBox BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  >
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>                
</ListBox>
```

This should work also with ListBoxItem-instances and is IMO less "work-around".

Comment: The border one works. However the background doesn't works like I expected, there's still a little bit of blue (the default selection background) in the left of selected item.

Comment: Set the Padding of the container to 0. See my example, I have changed it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the ItemsControl hint. I wasn't aware of that control.