# Listbox Item selection

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, listboxitem

I have a WPF project (C#, Visual Studio 2010, MVVM).

In this project I have a ListBox. When I select the items I am getting a blue box around my objects and I'm not sure where said box comes from. Obviously it's something to do with selection, but I'm not sure what to alter to get it to disappear.

The Listbox is here:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ChatNodeListViewModel.ChatNodeVMs, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" Background="Transparent" Name="LbNodes" SelectedItem="{Binding ChatNodeListViewModel.SelectedNode, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" >
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="2000" Height="1600"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding XCoord}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding YCoord}"/>
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="lb_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />

                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Thumb Name="myThumb" Template="{StaticResource NodeVisualTemplate}">

                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="DragDelta">
                                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ChatNodeListViewModel.DragDeltaCommand, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                                </i:EventTrigger>

                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </Thumb>
                    </Grid>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NodeVisualMode}" Value="0">
                            <Setter TargetName="myThumb" Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource NodeVisualTemplate}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NodeVisualMode}" Value="1">
                            <Setter TargetName="myThumb" Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource NodeTemplateTest}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NodeVisualMode}" Value="2">
                            <Setter TargetName="myThumb" Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource NodeTemplateTest2}" />
                        </DataTrigger>

                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

There is a main ControlTemplate which can be switched out for others (the main one being NodeVisualTemplate). But since this issue seems to happen on all of them, I'm inclined to believe it's further up the tree.

Still, I did do some testing for it, and will show it here:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="NodeVisualTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Border x:Name="_Border" Padding="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" BorderThickness="3" Margin="2" CornerRadius="5,5,5,5" BorderBrush="SteelBlue"                     Visibility="Visible">

                </Border>

            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="_Border" Property="Effect">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="Black" Opacity="1" BlurRadius="20" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter TargetName="_Border" Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                </DataTrigger>

            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

Within the border at the top of this template are some text boxes and stuff, but I don't suspect them as being part of the affair. The point is that I've changed the background of this control template. It is 'transparent' in the XAML above, but I've changed it to red and other colours to test. It doesn't get rid of the blue square that surrounds the ListBoxItem.

Here is an image of the horrible blue background I'm getting:

[image]

Can I get rid of it? Honestly I'm really at a loss.

Thanks.

**Edit:** I should mention something else I tried that is rather important here. I went up a layer into the ListBox.ItemContainerStyle part above and just under this line:

```
<EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="lb_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
```

I added this:

```
<Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" >
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
```

Did it work? No, it didn't. It didn't get rid of the big blue box. It did make my fonts bold though, so I know it at least had that effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Thumb is still generated inside of a ListBoxItem, Which has ControlTemplate of It's own.
You need to put in your ListBoxItem Style, a Setter for Template, and put in there only:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Content"/>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, could you clarify where this code should go?

Comment: <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding XCoord}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding YCoord}"/>
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="lb_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />

                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

Comment: And should it go before that code, after it or in the middle of it somewhere? I've tried all three and none worked.

Comment: You put in the middle as another Setter inside the ItemContainerStyle.
The  blue border you see come from the default ListBoxItem Tempalte, where they change its color upon selection.

Comment: Okay, I did that. So now that part looks like this:
<Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding XCoord}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding YCoord}"/>
                        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="lb_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
                        <Setter>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Content"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter>
Did not work.

Comment: Can you try installing "Snoop" (google: wpf snoop)?
It can show you visual tree at runtime. you can check where blue border comes from exactly...

Comment: I'm using WPF Inspector now (seems to do basically the same thing), but so far unable to figure it out. It seems each ListBoxItem contains a border called 'Bd'. This must be a system thing because I have created no such item (and it appears above the content presenter in the hierarchy). If I change the colour of the background of this 'Bd' then I can repeat the effect (the one I want to remove). But how to access this in XAML?

Comment: As I've said, the border comes from the default ListBoxItem Tempalte.
By overriding it's Template in your ItemContainerStyle you can remove it completely.

Comment: <Setter Property="Template"><Setter.Value> <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem"> <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Content"/> </ControlTemplate></Setter.Value> </Setter>

Comment: I guess I wrote my code incorrectly, for this works. Thank you for your patience. If you write it up as an answer, I will give you a tick for answering correctly.

Comment: Which... you did, clearly, as I'm replying to it. Marked as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a "standard" thing, wpf does for you in ListBoxes. It highlights the currently selected Item for you. I found a similar thread here: [WPF ListBox, how to hide border and change selected item background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351904/wpf-listbox-how-to-hide-border-and-change-selected-item-background-color)

They fixed it by adding this code to the listbox and setting the HighlightBrushKey to Transparent for this ListBox, did you try that in your case?

```
<ListBox BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  >
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>                
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but this did not work for me.